Were my original files deleted after cancelling a compression operation in WinRar
I want to know if due to cancelling an ongoing compression operation I might have deleted my files permanently. Does WinRAR delete after all files are archived or line by line ? Or does it confirm entire archive is made and then proceeds to delete.
Points:

There are too many files to manually check

I checked the box for deleting original files after archiving in WinRAR windows GUI,

Delete files is checked in Delete mode



I have never in 20 years of using WinRAR to know it to modify the files I was compressing.

To clarify your question, and please consider adding a line or two two make this point yourself in your own question: Are you asking if WinRAR, when you have told it to delete the source files after archiving them, deletes them AS IT GOES, or only AFTER IT VERIFIES THEY HAVE BEEN ADDED TO THE COMPLETED ARCHIVE?

By default, no, the source files would still be there. But "I checked the box for deleting original files after archiving in WinRAR windows GUI, Delete files is checked in Delete mode," (presumably, not Recycle Bin). Some or all have likely been deleted.
That said, if the files are of value, they might (or might not) be recoverable.

Stop using the source drive.
If of great value, take drive to professional recovery service -- but get an estimate on cost and likelihood of success.
If they're of moderate value, you can try the following:

Make a drive image (copy) of the drive(s) that held the files.
Put aside the original drive. If primary, then boot from rescue USB or DVD, e.g., Hiren's Boot CD PE.
Use recovery tools on the drive image to try to bring back recently deleted files. Hiren's Boot CD PE includes Recuva, DiskDigger and other utilities for that purpose.



Note that attempts at file recovery to the same drive will cause further loss or damage.

I don't need help with recovery. They aren't that important. I just need to know for future reference that cancelling a compression operation midway, well, how does it work actually? Since you say some or all or maybe none have been deleted. That confuses me. Are you not sure?

You do not know at what point the operation was canceled. Could be files were not yet deleted, could be they were gone. If you don't know, how would someone else??

Aight cool. That helps
